# Laptop randomly freeze due to graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04

I recently installed ubuntu 20.04 and I've had a few problems and most of them are resolved but the graphics drivers are really hard to fix. I have a HP spectre x360 15" with nvidia 1050ti max-q and i7-8750H.

So I have tried the official drivers 440,435 and 395 from software & updates. All of them give me the same problem, the computer totally freezes after 1-30 min. I have tried nouveau but with that it won't even boot. So to boot it up I added nomodeset to grub and interesting enough it now has been alive for more than 2,5h. Problem now tho is that my external display (through hdmi) is working as it should but the laptop display still shows the HP startup logo.

Also one thing that could be added is that it seems like when I install the nvidia drivers it all works as it should. I worked for a few hours the first time but then I went to bed and the next day when I started the computer I got these problems. I have tried to reinstall everything and same thing here it worked until I restarted the computer.

I have tried to look at the logs and I have seen the "NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 79, pid=1102, GPU has fallen off the bus." quite often (always in the top), not every time tho.

One question that struck my mind now is that with nomodeset I still get the nvidia driver up and running which might mean that its the intel graphics that

lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' give me

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
DeviceName: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Totally confused about what to do next